# Crystal Reports Web Viewer - formatting issues in crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I'm using a Crystal Reports Web Viewer to display a CR report. It works perfectly fine in a CR Designer preview, however when I view it in a browser (any) the crosstab does not look as expected:

[image: crosstab badly formatted]

Specifically, column and row names have an additional margin added (values are displayed correctly) which cases the problem. I tried to change paragraph margin settings in my site's css file, but it doesn't make any difference. What could be causing this problem and how could this be solved?

When I change the specific p element margin property using Firebug, it displays correctly:

[image: crosstab fixed]

Comment: Hi. How did you get this to work please I am struggling to display anything except a load error. VS2013 IIS8 Windows 2012 Server. SQL 2012. Works in designer. Doesn't work when deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a Crystal Reports bug which affects 13.0.4 Version, it works fine when you run the same report using the 13.0.3 (and probably earlier) version. This bug is known to the CR team but won't be fixed till October (3 months to fix something that worked fine previously...): http://scn.sap.com/thread/3207181

Just love Crystal...